# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I am trying to get a pi camera working on raspberry pi, I got this connection refused error (see title). I attempted a traceroute test, to make sure its sucesfully connecting to the server, but its not connecting for some reason, even though traceroute succesfully goes from my local computer to the iot server. This is the code.

```
camera.py:11: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camera.py", line 42, in <module>
    client.connect(BROKER, PORT, 60)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 768, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 895, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(sf._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 712, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 703, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused"
```

python code:

```
import picamera
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import hashlib

LED =  16
SWITCH = 20

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

BROKER = "some broker, taken out for security "
PORT = 1883
QOS = 1
data_block_size = 2000

STATE1 = 0
STATE2 = 1
STATE3 = 2
STATE4 = 3
state = STATE1
GPIO.setup(SWITCH, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
camera = picamera.PiCamera()

def my_callback(channel):
    global state
    if(state== STATE1):
        state = STATE2

def on_publish(client, userdata, result):
    print("image published")

GPIO.add_event_detect(SWITCH, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback,bouncetime=200)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(BROKER, PORT, 60)
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.subscribe("xxxxxphotobooth")
client.loop_start
try:
    while True:
        if(state == STATE2):
            blink_time = 0.5
            for count in range(10):
                GPIO.output(LED, True)
                time.sleep(blink_time)
                GPIO.output(LED, False)
                time.sleep(blink_time)
                blink_time += 0.05
                state = STATE3
        elif(state == STATE3):
            camera.start_preview()
            time.sleep(3)
            camera.capture('image.jpg')
            camera.stop_preview()
            GPIO.output(LED, True)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output(LED, False)
            state = STATE4
        elif(state == STATE4):
            #upload to broker
            f=open("image.jpg", "rb")
            fileContent = f.read()
            byteArr = bytearray(fileContent)
            client.publish("xxxxx/photobooth", byteArr, 0)
            state = STATE1

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Just because you can traceroute to the remote machine doesn't mean you can connect to port 1883 on that machine. 1) are you sure there is a broker running on the remote machine, 2) Can you connect with another client (e.g. mosquitto_pub)

Comment: 1) The broker is a school iot server, so yes, im sure the broker is running correctly, since other groups are working on differnet projects related to MQTT cocurrently. 2) As far a config im pretty sure my school (university) has it configured correctly

Comment: That wasn't the second question, the question was can you reach the broker with another MQTT client from the same machine you are running the code on